# fetching Unique value in React from map?

Tags: reactjs

I want to fetch unique value of countryCode from the below code.

```
                 {
                    respDcNumber.map((user, i) =>
                      <MenuItem value={user.countryCode}>{user.countryCode}</MenuItem>)
                  }
```

Comment: please mention your complete code.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
const countryCodes = [];
respDcNumber.map((user, i) => {
    // Only return if it's not already in the list
    if (!countryCodes.includes(user.countryCode)) {
        countryCodes.push(user.countryCode);
        return <MenuItem value={user.countryCode}>{user.countryCode}</MenuItem>;
    }
    return null;
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this use `Set` to get unique countryCode values and map it.

```
{
    [...new Set(uniqueUsers.map(x=>x.countryCode))].map(code =>
    <MenuItem key={code.countryCode} value={code.countryCode}>{code.countryCode}</MenuItem>)
}
```